# É possível executar um Body Cascade dentro de uma sub área não retangular?

Tags: opencv, detecção-de-colisão

após estudar um pouco e a ajuda de pessoas bem orientadas aqui entendi que o OpenCV manipula imagens (uma matriz) que sempre será retangular. Portanto, uma ROI nunca será poligonal.

Gostaria de saber se é possível aplicar um Body Cascade (detector de pessoas) numa sub região da imagem em forma não retangular.

Por exemplo, na imagem (https://imageshack.com/i/pm4a4PzCj) tenho um vídeo sendo rodado e ao aplicar o body cascade ele detecta "todas as pessoas" na imagem. Minha dúvida é:

E se a região de interesse fosse uma subregião em formato não retangular, como mostra a imagem (https://imageshack.com/i/pmzMUm2sj). **É possível executar o Body Cascade somente dentro dessa área em vermelho (uma área não retangular)?**

Até agora não consegui encontrar uma solução para esse problema =(. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Obrigado!

Comment: Felipe, meu caro, eu já te expliquei *inúmeras vezes* que isso que você **diz** que quer fazer não tem sentido! Vou falar mais uma: **não há** como limitar a execução do Cascade a uma região que não seja retangular, simplesmente porque o algoritmo espera uma imagem (que é inerentemente retangular). O que você quer fazer é limitar a detecção das pessoas apenas na região demarcada, e a resposta eu já te dei [lá na sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183698/como-identificar-se-a-%c3%a1rea-de-um-objeto-est%c3%a1-ou-n%c3%a3o-dentro-de-uma-outra-%c3%a1rea-des).

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição lá na sua pergunta original pra tentar deixar bem claro dessa vez. E votei esta como duplicata daquela.